# is there a tab control in RichFaces or JSF that doesn't render ugly nested tables?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, facelets

The RichFaces 3.3.3 tabPanel control that I'm currently using renders 4 level nested tables. Is there any other tab control to render clean HTML or atleast allow me to control it? Like a `<ul>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of ugly code (and it is not only related to the `<rich:tab>` component) is used in order to assure a compatibilities and identical behaviors among all browsers, including all IE (and IE6 also), Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and so on...

That's why the HTML code, as well as the Javascript code, is not optimized by the Richfaces components.

If it is a problem for you, you can try to use your own components (some examples have been provided by *org.life.java*).

Eventually you can also simulate this behavior with buttons and some Javascript (that will hide or show different panels) or using one `<a4j:commandButton>` per tab to refresh the content of a basic panel.

Answer (score 0):

RichFaces 4 will be switching to div's for layout in many components.

Comment: The Richfaces showcase in version 4.3.4  at least still has tables for the tabs in rich:tabPanel.